# What does it really mean if a TCP session gets hijacked?

Tags: man-in-the-middle

Can TCP session hijacking be used to intercept (and modify the contents sent by the client) a simple TCP socket-based client/server connection? I read somewhere that this was not possible.

And I am trying to understand what [this](http://www.cloudtacker.com/BGP-MiTM-attacks) is.

Can anyone please tell me more about the link above, the page was not too informative.

Answer (score 1):

If you are an **active** man in the middle who can **read and modify** the traffic (as in the case of the link you have in your question) then TCP hijacking is possible since you can capture the packets from both sides and modify both content and TCP header (and thus also the sequence numbers) before forwarding.

> I read somewhere that this was not possible.

It is hard to tell what you've really read and where but I assume that you were reading about **blind** TCP hijacking. In this case the attacker can **only inject** traffic but does not see the original traffic nor can stop the original traffic. In this situation it is much harder (although not fully impossible) to hijack the TCP connection since the attacker need to guess the correct sequence numbers and ports instead of having the correct sequence numbers from the captured traffic.